# Provide empty value to an argument in linux command

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I have a shell script where I can pass two arguments.

1st argument can be empty or a string
2nd argument can be 0 or 1

Now I want to provide empty value to first argument and 1 to 2nd, how could I call it?

```
mycommand ___ 1
```

what should be the value at __
???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just pass an empty string as the first argument:

```
mycommand '' 1
```